# RTK Query "merge-patch+json" content type ruins request body

Tags: javascript, api-platform.com, rtk-query

I am using RTK Query mutation to update my entities. There is api-platform on the backend that accepts only "**application/merge-patch+json**" Content-Type with PATCH requests.
If I try to put this in my mutation's **return** statement:

```
method: 'PATCH',
headers: {
  "Content-Type": 'application/merge-patch+json'
},
```

I get only **[object Object]** in my request body instead of json. However, if i change my method to "PUT" or Content-Type to "**application/json**", my request body is as expected and contains valid json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchBaseQuery` does not know that content-type by default. In that case instead of passing

```
  body: something
```

from your `query`,
you need to pass

```
  body: JSON.stringify(something)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much! Btw, your product is awesome!